# posts_per_page returns one extra post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get latest two posts. I'm trying to use following query, but for some strange reasons it is returning me one extra post (total 3 posts instead of 2). Similarly if i put 3 in the query, it will return 4 posts.
Why this is happening and how can I fix it? Thanks.

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=2' ); ?>
    <?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>                       
        <?php endwhile; endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `posts_per_page=1`?

Comment: And why this got -1 ? The question was to know the whats wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycatname&showposts=2'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

No need for `wp_reset_query`; this loop can be used multiple times in a template.

Delete the `category_name=mycatname&` if you don't need the category name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i figured out what was causing problem. It was sticky post. '&ignore_sticky_posts=1' solved it.